# 32 bit service works Windows 7 not in 10. When Allied Telesis driver is installed the service still starts but no logging is done by the service

Tags: services

There is no real code here that has changed. The service starts at bootup, I have tried the delayed start of the service without luck. I went back to a previous version Build 1607 x64 Windows 10. In that case I found that when an ethernet driver(Allied-Telesis) is disabled and after a reboot the logging function works. When running with x64 Windows 10 version 1909 that trick does not work. I have not tried running on this system without the Allied-Telesis driver installed. I do have another system which I have to Remote Desktop into, this is running build 1909 but is a server and as such I can't install the Telesis driver. The logging function works on that system. The service receives packets over a private network and concatenates the packets into log files. It is just NAICT your standard 32 bit Windows service albeit a custom service designed by my predecessors.

Comment: 1609 doesn’t exist do you mean 1607 or some other version?

Comment: Your description is very unclear.

Comment: What is the Allied Telesis driver? A driver working on one quite old OS and not working on a much newer OS isn't surprising, especially considering the architectural differences between those very different OSes. Have you gone to the publisher to look for an updated driver that is written for the newer system?

Comment: Allied-Telesis is an ethernet PCI card that we can connect an HP printer to. The install of the A-T and HP drivers works 'fine', no errors seen. I can print files from my application(not the service). I have contacted A-T but they have not responded back to me yet.

Comment: More information. was able to use netstat -a -b and found my service is connected to the printer IP address (Allied Telesis ethernet address). If I leave the printer off and restart the system my service gets connected to the Host IP ethernet card and the logging function works. I can turn the Printer back on after the reboot and the logging continues. The code is old. Guessing I am going to have to tie the service startup with the Host IP Address somehow.